# Failed to start the session: already started

Tags: php, symfony, session, view, csrf

I have installed the packages Google-mailer, doctrine -fixtures-bundle, and webpack-bundle. I'm at the beginning of this project and there to create the first controller which should have a form to login. Controller and From were created with the commands bin/console make: controller and make: form, and not changed. But I already have a problem because I get an error when I call the form

> Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.

I can explain this message with the fact that when creating the view Symfony tries to start a session because the form is protected with csrf (which should stay that way). But this should not be a problem because Symfony manages the sessions.

php.ini => session.auto_start=0;

framework.yaml:

```
    framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true
```

Test function in HomeController:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/testform", name="testform", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function testform()
    {
        $User = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(TestFormType::class, $User);
        $form->handleRequest($this->request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        return $this->render('home/testform.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

TestFormType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('forname')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('password');
    }
```

[image]

Comment: because i will use flash message and i already have flash message tag in my base.html.twig the error might be caused by the fact that i already open a session when Symfony checks if there are flash messages. So maybe I might have to check if a session is already open like: [Avoid Starting Sessions for Anonymous User](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/session/avoid_session_start.html) **{% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}**  _I will find out tonight_

Comment: As you have stated, Symfony manages sessions and I have yet to encounter these sorts of problems when staying inside of Symfony.  Make sure you are not directly including any outside code that might be messing with the session.  Make sure you are not using $_SESSION or any of the session_ functions directly.  And a bit off-topic but [avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.

Comment: I think i found the error. I created several new sessions in my project by doing 
**(new Session())->getFlashbag()->add(...)** to grab my messages. 
i just realized that this is a big mistake.